# Emojione sprite

Tags: emoji, emojione

I started to use [Emojione](http://emojione.com/) for my own chat application. I need to add emoji  (like telegram or whatsapp) and emojione works well for this job. But how I can list all the emoji like this pic?

[image]

I look [sprites documentation](https://demos.emojione.com/sprites-png.html), but there is a way for add all emoji (diveded by category) without list all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest this for emojione: 
https://github.com/mervick/emojionearea

require emojione and jquery